# Почему появляется ошибка AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute send

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Разбираюсь с SQLAlchemy и FastAPI. Сделал роутер и инициализировал базу, но почему-то на первой строке роутера вылетает ошибка:

```
INFO:     ::1:55018 - "GET /api/v1/places/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 772, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\dmm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1106, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 274, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\api\v1\endpoints\places.py", line 15, in get_by_query
    places = await session.execute(select(PlacelistTable))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\session.py", line 455, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 190, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2308, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2190, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in execute
    return meth(
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2346, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 591, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 125, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 185, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 527, in _prepare_and_execute
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 861, in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 810, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 859, in _start_transaction
    await self._transaction.start()
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\transaction.py", line 146, in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\dmm\testProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 350, in execute
    result = await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 374, in query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 367, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol.query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\coreproto.pyx", line 1094, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._simple_query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 966, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._write
  File "C:\Users\dmm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 366, in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
  File "C:\Users\dmm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 402, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Не могу понять, почему она появляется. Прошел дебаггером - всё создается. В `async def get_all(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)) -> list[Place]:` сессия не None и у нее стоит статус `is_active`. Не знаете, в чем может быть проблема?

```
_session_maker: async_sessionmaker | None = None


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with _session_maker() as session:
        yield session


async def init_db():
    global _session_maker
    engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test")
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    _session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
```

```
@place_router.get("/")
async def get_all(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)) -> list[Place]:
    places = await session.execute(select(PlaceTable))
    places = placelists.scalars().all()
    return places
```

```
async def main():
    await init_db()
    app = FastAPI(title=APP_NAME, version=API_VERSION)
    app.include_router(api_router)
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(asyncio.run(main()), host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки полностью, с полным трейсбэком

Comment: @insolor добавил

Comment: init_db() как-то вызывается?

Comment: У меня предположение, что на момент вызова get_session функция init_db еще не вызвана, из-за этого в _session_maker лежит None. По коду не понятно как init_db вообще вызывается. Я бы вместо глобальной переменной сделал, чтобы init_db сама возвращала session_maker, и обернул бы в асинхронный кэширующий декоратор (https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru), чтобы она выполнялась только один раз фактически, а дальше одно и то же значение возвращалось.

Comment: Что-то такое, только асинхронный вариант и с асинхронным кэшем: https://github.com/insolor/Experimental_FastAPI_PyJWT_SQLAlchemy_Docker/blob/main/inside/database.py

Comment: @insolor спасибо за ответ, добавил в вопрос еще как вызывается `init_db`

Comment: Вот что пишут в интернетах, хотя не знаю, как это поможет: "loop._proactor is None means loop.close() was called before session.close() call. This is incorrect; and not aiohttp problem." Собственно, самая верхняя ошибка говорит о том же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется какая-то проблема с тем как вы запускаете приложение:

```
async def main():
    await init_db()
    app = FastAPI(title=APP_NAME, version=API_VERSION)
    app.include_router(api_router)
    return app


uvicorn.run(asyncio.run(main()), host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Предположения такие:

- на момент вызова `get_session` вероятно функция `init_db` или не успела выполниться, или не запускается вообще (или запускалась в другом процессе), из-за этого в переменной `_session_maker` лежит `None`;
- либо проблема из-за того, что через `asyncio.run` эвент луп запускается, потом завершается, и uvicorn по какой-то причине не может создать новый.

При запуске под отладчиком возможно функция успевает выполниться, или еще какие-то особенности запуска под отладчиком помогают.

Я бы посоветовал избавиться от использования глобальной переменной, вместо этого сделать, чтобы `init_db` возвращало `session_maker`, и добавить ей асинхронный кэширующий декоратор (например, [async-lru](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru)), чтобы она выполнялась один раз, а потом просто возвращала одно и то же значение:

```
from async_lru import alru_cache  # pip install async-lru


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    session_maker = await get_session_maker()
    async with session_maker() as session:
        yield session


@alru_cache()
async def get_session_maker():
    engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test")
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    return async_sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
```

Роутер без изменений, а основной файл приводите к "каноническому" виду:

```
app = FastAPI(title=APP_NAME, version=API_VERSION)
app.include_router(api_router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Comment: Тут можно было бы использовать dependency injection для получения session_maker, но вроде бы вшитый в FastAPI не умеет делать DI для произвольных функций. Можно попробовать какой-нибудь отдельный DI фреймворк.